# SQL Birthday Query

Tags: mysql

Hey I'm a bit of a beginner with SQL but i'm trying to write a query to pull out all records if its someones birthday within the next 7 days and have looked at other threads with answers but I'm having trouble adapting them to my setup.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `QG04c`
    WHERE month( `dob` ) = month( now( ) )
    AND day( `dob` )
    BETWEEN day( now( ) )
    AND day( now( ) ) +7
    AND `Primary Unit?` =1
```

At the moment this pulls out everyone whose birthday is within 7 days but I don't think it will cope with end of the month scenarios and end of year etc.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: It appears to be MySQL based on the backticks, but hope the OP confirms

Comment: Rather than comparing year, month and day, construct full dates and compare them.

Comment: Pretty sure it is MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is MySQL, you can use the [DAYOFYEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear) function to get the day of the year a birthday occurs. The simple scenario is everything from 1st Jan - 25th December, where 7 days ahead is in the same year. For this you can use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `QG04c`
WHERE   DAYOFYEAR(DOB) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 7;
```

However when today is between 25th Dec - 31st Dec you need to account for the birthday being between 1st and 6th Jan. To do this you need:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `QG04c`
WHERE   DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) < 7
AND     DAYOFYEAR(DOB) < DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Then it is just a matter of combining the two cases:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `QG04c`
WHERE   DAYOFYEAR(DOB) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
OR  (   DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY) < 7
    AND DAYOFYEAR(DOB) < DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    );
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/335d5/15)**

Comment: Please be aware that leap years can change the day of the year!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename WHERE [ColumnName] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, +7, @YourDate) AND @YourDate and Primary Unit = 1 (If you have and condition put add here)
```

Thanks .

Comment: hi MatthewShine, @yourdate means you need to convert the date to which format you want. For example SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY"). So many format is available. That is why i'm telling

Comment: sorry but you have to talk to me like im a complete idiot, basically the dates in the table are YYYY/MM/DD so would i need SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD") in place of @yourdate?

Comment: i've now got this but it says im not using the right syntax after SimpleDateFormat on line 3 :( and it's gonna look messy as i can't even get the format right to put it as code in a comment...


SELECT *
FROM `QG04c`
WHERE dob BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, +7, SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD")) AND SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD")
AND `Primary Unit?` =1

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy if you don't decompose the day?

```
WHERE `dob` BETWEEN now() AND now() +7
```

Comment: Only if they are going to be born in the next 7 days. Anyone born in the past would not satisfy the criteria. i.e. someone born on 1st March 1970 has a birthday in the next seven days, but their date of birth is not between now() and now() + 7.